# Clicking on newly created Vector layer in unit testing (Jasmine)

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, angular

I've created a component that attaches a new vector layer on the click of a polygon.
I've used custom interactions of openlayers to do so (using ol/pointer).
I need to click on a particular coordinate on the newly created Vector layer.
The issue I'm seeing is when clicking on a specific coordinate on the polygon, it tries to click on the polygon layer and not on the newly added one.

How do I solve this issue?
PS:
As I've used Angular for creation of the component. I'm using Jasmine for testing

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using `map.renderSync()`. Hope this helps.